# Migrating from Existing MySQL Setup to WordPress

Tags: mysql, migration

I currently have a database with the following schema:

Table: Articles Columns: ID, Title, Author, Content

Table: Authors Columns: ID, AuthorName, EmailAddress

Table: Categories Columns: ID, CategoryName

I'm interested in moving this over to WordPress. I do NOT actually need to preserve the authors or categories tables because we are revamping those sections in the migration. However I DO need to save certain rows (or all, if easier) of the articles table. This includes keeping the author ID linked to it. I'm willing to do manual queries in order to select which rows I want to move over to the new table, but I'm not sure exactly where I should do this. So my question is: How can I move these articles over to WordPress in the easiest, most seamless fashion?

Bonus points if I'm able to assign authors on import somehow.

Comment: How much WordPress experience do you have?

Comment: Basic experience. I've not coded plugins or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're fairly well-versed in [WordPress plugin development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin), you could write a couple plugins, one to create your users with [`wp_create_user()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user), and another to insert your articles as Posts using [`wp_insert_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) (which, among other things, allows you to specify the `post_author` on each post that you insert).

If you're not so comfortable writing plugins, then there are a couple of tools that might make your life easier.  One is [Import Users from CSV](http://wordpress.org/plugins/import-users-from-csv/) -- I've never used this plugin, but it sounds like something that might work for you.  Once you've got your users created, WordPress has some import tools built in to the backend at **Tools > Import**.  If you can craft an RSS feed for your existing articles -- or if you've already got one -- you can import your articles using the RSS importer.

If that doesn't work out for you, there are [a host of "importer" plugins](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=import+posts) to try.  My only recommendation is to backup your database *before* you try any of them.

**Edited to Add** -- there's a Codex page on [importing content](http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content) -- it may answer some questions for you.

Comment: Firstly, I'm not familiar with plugin development as I've never done it before, so your second suggestion is probably more where I'm looking. I should also mention, though, that keeping the user list isn't super important as I only have 2 (3 including admin account) so I could manually enter those again. The important part is assigning the articles to those users.

Comment: If you can use the WordPress native import functions -- probably the RSS importer, in your case -- then you can assign authors to the posts on import.  Create the users first, obviously.  I don't know how easy/difficult it might be to map authors to articles using one of the plugins.  Good luck!